# Excel: Update table across workbooks while protecting given column from being overwritten?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a file (let's call it OVERLORD.xlsm) which contains a table. In subfolders, I have files called (OVERLORD-north.xlsm, OVERLORD-east.xlsm) etc. which all use data connections to fetch the table stored in OVERLORD.xlsm.

Within each sub-file, for example OVERLORD-north, I want to be able to enter some information that will be persistent even when I update the table's data connection.

Let's say the following is contained in OVERLORD.xlsm (col A contains a static autonumber that I am using as an index):

```
Col A - Col B - Col C  
1         2
```

These contents will be echoed into OVERLORD-north, but if I enter something in col C (from within OVERLORD-North), this information is overwritten the next time I refresh information from the original file.

Can I stop this?

Can I lock columns in some way to prevent their contents from being overwritten, even though they are part of a table? Or can I choose to omit certain columns from a data refresh query? Literally any solution that allows me to create persistence for only given cells or columns in an externally fetched table will be of interest.

And yes, it's necessary that the columns be part of the table, otherwise they aren't sortable with the index key, which is a prerequisite. I also can't keep all the information in a single file, that would have been my choice months ago if it were at all possible.

I have a workaround in mind, but it's going to kill the resource effectiveness... So I'll appreciate any input on locking the columns, or if that's not possible, suggestions for improving the stability and speed of my column-preservation-array-maker.

```
Sub rewriteStatus()
' Loop through array, match index number between array and sheet, and write to corresponding cell(s) into the table.
End Sub


Sub preserveStatus()
    Dim statusArray() As String, emptyRow As Boolean

    ReDim Preserve statusArray(1 To 4, 1 To 2)    
    emptyRow = True

    For i = 2 To ListObject("PUSH_table").Count
        If Cells(i, 14) <> "" Then
            statusArray(i, 2) = Cells(i, 14).Value
            emptyRow = False
        End If
        If Cells(i, 15) <> "" Then
            statusArray(i, 3) = Cells(i, 15).Value
            emptyRow = False
        End If
        If Cells(i, 17) <> "" Then
            statusArray(i, 4) = Cells(i, 17).Value
            emptyRow = False
        End If
        ' ReDim array if any cell of that row was found to be non-empty
        ' and copy the index key for that row
        If emptyRow = False Then 
            ReDim Preserve statusArray(1 To 2, 1 To UBound(statusArray, 2) + 1)
            statusArray(i, 1) = Cells(i, 1).Value
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to stop syncing col3 from overlord all-together? Or just sync overlord to overlord-north where col3 can't overwrite anything that's already in col3 of -north?

Comment: Those two alternatives are synonymous in my specific case. Anything written to col 3 in overlord by other files won't show up in overlord-north anyway, due to an autofilter and how the files are being used. That is to say, there is a second index column that specifices which category the information belongs to, and the sub-files all filter based on this index.

Comment: I would think editing the sql query in the connection would work, but I can't manage to do it.

Comment: Is it even possible to do that for an Excel-to-Excel data connection without using ADODB?

Comment: In VBA, I'm not sure. Using the query you can use OLEDB, *I think*.